# Container jenkins não encontra comando docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

em resumo, estou tentando executar um container dentro de outro. Onde o primeiro container a subir é baseado numa imagem jenkins e o segundo numa imagem gcc (que é apenas para teste).

esse é o passo a passo do que eu fiz:

1. Levantei um container jenkins baseado na imagem `jenkins\jenkins` com o seguinte comando:

   - `docker run -it -p 1234:8080 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -u 0 jenkins/jenkins`
   - `jenkins_home` é um volume criado com o comando `docker volume create jenkins_home`
2. Instalei os plugins Docker, Docker Slaves e Docker Pipeline.
3. Criei um job pipeline:

   ```
   pipeline {
       stages {        
           stage('Container') {
               agent {
                   docker {
                       image 'gcc'
                       args '-v ${nomedocurso}:/curso/'
                   }
               }
               steps {
                   sh 'ls -l'
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   - Nesse passo, o jenkins não estava encontrando o docker:

     > + docker inspect -f . gcc
     >   /var/jenkins_home/workspace/curso-c@2@tmp/durable-ee333f1e/script.sh: 1: 
     >   /var/jenkins_home/workspace/curso-c@2@tmp/durable-ee333f1e/script.sh: 
     >   docker: not found
4. Tentei incluir o parâmetro label:

   ```
   pipeline {
       agent {
           label 'docker' 
       }
       stages {        
           stage('Container') {
               agent {
                   docker {
                       label 'docker'
                       image 'gcc'
                       args '-v ${nomedocurso}:/curso/'
                   }
               }
               steps {
                   sh 'ls -l'
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   - Porém o Jenkins continuou reclamando:

     > Still waiting to schedule task
     >   ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘docker’

---

- Porque o Docker não está sendo encontrado pelo Jenkins?
- Como configuro e executo um pipeline com docker em um dos estágios?

Comment: Essa image do Jenkins não possui o docker engine instalado. Se você deseja manusear containers usando uma imagem com Jenkins e Docker a melhor solução é provisionar uma com tudo que você precisa.

Comment: @AntonioAzambuja vc conhece alguma para recomendar?

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Não se deve iniciar um container dentro de outro container. Apesar de não ser impossível, simplesmente não deveria ser feito e "fere" os propósitos dos containers.

Este artigo (em inglês) fala um pouco sobre isso e apresenta uma alternativa. Inclusive me parece que é para um cenário similar ao seu: https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd

Há também um projeto que permite fazer isso de uma forma mais simples, mas depende das imagens estarem disponíveis no projeto: https://www.testcontainers.org/

Comment: Isso me ajuda um pouco. Porém, como estou no windows não consigo achar o docker.sock! O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: @GabrielHardoim ja tentou sem `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`?

Comment: nem cheguei a testar esse volume ainda